# How do you factor the following cubic polynomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring, cubics

How do you factor the following polynomial?

$$1-x-x^2-x^3$$

So far, I've got numerical solutions, for example, I know $(0.543689 - x)$ is a factor , but I would really like to have an exact form for the factors, namely a form like the following:

$$(1-ax)(1-bx)(1-cx)$$

with $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Not that I like to bear bad news, but what makes you think there *is* such a nice closed form to begin with?

Comment: looks like your solution is the only real one and wolfram says that its exact form is given by $x = \frac{1}{3}\big(-1 - \frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{17 + 3 \sqrt{33}}} + \sqrt[3]{17 + 3 \sqrt{33}}\big)$

Comment: This polynomial is irreducible over the rationals, as can be seen from the rational root theorem (and the fact that neither $1$ nor $-1$ are roots) or from Eisenstein's criterion (after substituting $x+1$ for $x$). To factor it you'll need the cubic formula.

Comment: only one root is real

Comment: I would like to have the imaginary factors. I'll just quickly edit my question to reflect that.

Comment: I would like to have the exact form of the imaginary factors, could you post a link to the wolfram function you used?

Comment: If you factor Surb's solution you get a quadratic equation!

Comment: Trying to work with Tribonacci numbers?

Comment: yeah. I got a closed form expression for it, possibly. Needs testing. I'm trying to improve my skill at generating functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has only one real root (it is a decreasing function), you can find it using Cardano's method.

For this, you have to eliminate the term in $x^2$. For this, it will be simpler to change all signs. Thus
\begin{align}
x^3+x^2+x-1&=\Bigl(x+\frac13\Bigr)^3-\frac13x-\frac1{27}+x-1=\Bigl(x+\frac13\Bigr)^3+\frac23x-\frac{28}{27}\\[1ex]
&=\Bigl(x+\frac13\Bigr)^3+\frac23\Bigl(x+\frac13\Bigr)-\frac29-\frac{28}{27}\\[1ex]
&=\Bigl(x+\frac13\Bigr)^3+\frac23\Bigl(x+\frac13\Bigr)-\frac{34}{27}.
\end{align}
Setting $t=x+\dfrac13$, one has to solve $\;t^3+\dfrac23t-\dfrac{34}{27}=0$.

For this, set again $t=u+v$ and obtain
\begin{align}
t^3+\dfrac23t-\dfrac{34}{27}&=u^3+v^3+3uv(u+v)+\frac23(u+v)-\frac{34}{27}\\
&=u^3+v^3+(u+v)\Bigl(3uv+\frac23\Bigr)-\frac{34}{27}=0.
\end{align}
Add the condition $\;3uv=-\dfrac23$ to simplify this last equation. We obtain the system:
$$\begin{cases}u^3+v^3=\dfrac{34}{27}\\[1ex]uv=-\dfrac 29\end{cases}\iff\begin{cases}u^3+v^3=\dfrac{34}{27}\\[1ex]u^3v^3=-\dfrac 8{729}\end{cases}$$
So finally, it comes down to this classic high-school problem: find two numbers, given their sum $s$ and their product $p$. The solutions consist of the roots of the quadratic equation
$$z^2-sz+p=0.$$

Comment: Thank you for the help. Can I copy your answer as is in my proof?

Comment: Maybe you should end the computation, add some details and obtain the explicit formula for the root (which should not be simple…)

Comment: Yeah, I know, I'll do all that, just am I allowed to use your proof?

Comment: No problem. I haven't copyrighted it…

Answer (score 2):

Deflate the polynomial by setting $y:=x+\frac13$ and you get

$$y^3+\frac23y+\frac{34}{27},$$ also, with $z=3y$,

$$z^3+6z+34=0.$$

Then let $z=u^{1/3}-2u^{-1/3}$. Plugging in the equation, and after simplification,

$$u+34-\frac8u=0$$ or
$$u^2+34u-8=0.$$

The solutions of the quadratic equation are

$$\pm3\sqrt{33}-17.$$

Finally,

$$x=\frac13\left(\sqrt[3]{3\sqrt{33}-17}-\dfrac2{\sqrt[3]{3\sqrt{33}-17}}-1\right)$$ which matches the answer given by WA.

Comment: Vieta's substitution, I guess. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: yep. After all , the resolution of the cubic isn't so terrible.

Comment: I had a nice case in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2405575/how-to-get-thickness-of-a-spherical-shell-based-on-radius-and-volume/2405599#2405599 May I confess my love for the trigonometric solution and even more for the case where only one root is real. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I must admit that Iam not fond of the trigonometric solution because it requires the use of "costly" and "unnatural" transcendental functions. But my argument is pretty weak because extraction of the cubic roots is usually done by logarithms as well, and the case of cubic roots of complex arguments makes the trigonometric functions quite natural.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I was recently pleased to see that the resolution of the quartic (Euler's way) isn't so arduous as all computations are done in the reals (but for the solution of a cubic). But more impressively, the quintic can be reduced to the simple equation $x^5-x=a$, which amounts to a new, simple, special function (recall https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2396228/65203). Anyway, the reduction to this form requires tremendous computation, barely doable by hand.

Comment: Yes, I know this work and it is really impressive. The way quartic are solved looks like magics (in the most noble sense of the word). Thanks for remembering all these nice things.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I also understood this simple thing: to solve a quartic, you *must* solve a cubic (and also a quadratic). Because if there was a shorcut, you could solve a cubic by multiplying it by $x$ to obtain a quartic, and taking the shortcut. [More generally, to solve an $n^{th}$ degree equation, you *must* solve equations of all lower degrees.]