# How to get thickness of a spherical shell based on radius and volume?

Tags: geometry, arithmetic, volume

I have a problem converting an equation. I want to flip an independent to dependent.

Volume of a spherical shell is:

$$V= \frac{4}{3}\pi\bigl[(R+t)^3-(R-t)^3\bigl]$$

Where R is radius, t is half of shell's thickness. It is important to me that it has a form of ± t rather than the most common $V= \frac{4}{3}\pi\bigl[R^3-(R-2t)^3\bigl]$

How to turn the equation to have the following form?: $$t(V,R) = ...$$

I know it must be simple but no matter what I do, I end up with R somehow tangled to t. Please, help. I am getting mad...

Comment: I'm not saying is the case here, but some times things like this may not have algebraic solution. For example given a capsule shape fuel tank with given height of fluid of constant density, it is not possible to give a closed form algebraic solution to the volume in the tank. Ie, measuring contents of pill shaped capsule fuel tank by dipping ruler in it. In fact it is similar to solving for eccentric anomoly in two body gravitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematica gives:

$$t(V,R)=\frac{2\cdot(2\pi)^{1/3}R^2}{\left(-3V+\sqrt{256\pi^2R^6+9V^2}\right)^{1/3}}-\frac{\left(-3V+\sqrt{256\pi^2R^6+9V^2}\right)^{1/3}}{2\cdot(2\pi)^{1/3}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Starting from $$V= \frac{4}{3}\pi\bigl[(R+t)^3-(R-t)^3\bigl]=\frac{4}{3}\pi\left(6 R^2 t+2 t^3 \right)$$ and intoducing $$x=\frac t R \qquad\text{and}\qquad b=\frac{3 V}{8 \pi  R^3}$$ we end with a cubic equation $$x^3+3x-b=0\tag 1$$ Now, let $x=y-\frac 1y$ to get $$y^6-b y^3-1=0 $$ which is a quadratic in $y^3$ making the analytical real solution of$(1)$ to be 
$$y^3=\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2+4}}{2}\qquad \implies \qquad\color{red}{x=\sqrt[3]{\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2+4}}{2}}-\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{b+\sqrt{b^2+4}}}}\tag 2$$

Assuming that $t$ is small, you can also write $$t=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\, b^{2i-1} \tag 3$$ which will give by identification $$a_1=\frac{1}{3}\qquad a_2=-\frac{1}{81}\qquad a_3=\frac{1}{729}\qquad a_4=-\frac{4}{19683}\qquad a_5=\frac{55}{1594323}\tag 4$$ and so on.

This is in fact the Taylor expansion of $(2)$ built around $b=0$.

In order to check, we can use $(1)$ for given value of $x$ to deduce $b$ and from $b$ recompute $x$ from the expansion. Below are the results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
x_{given} & b_{calc} & x_{calc} \\
 0.00 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 \\
 0.05 & 0.150125 & 0.050000 \\
 0.10 & 0.301000 & 0.100000 \\
 0.15 & 0.453375 & 0.150000 \\
 0.20 & 0.608000 & 0.200000 \\
 0.25 & 0.765625 & 0.250000 \\
 0.30 & 0.927000 & 0.300002 \\
 0.35 & 1.092880 & 0.350014 \\
 0.40 & 1.264000 & 0.400064 \\
 0.45 & 1.441130 & 0.450253 \\
 0.50 & 1.625000 & 0.500879
\end{array}
\right)$$ which seems to be a quite good approximation.

**Edit**

Nicer would be to use the hyperbolic solution for one real root. This would give $$x=2 \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)\right)\tag 5$$ that is to say $$\color{red}{t=2 R \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{3 V}{16 \pi  R^3}\right)\right)}\tag 6$$ which is the exact formula you are looking for.

Comment: Using $b=2c$ gives something nicer $$y=c+\sqrt{c^2+1}\implies x= c+\sqrt{c^2+1}-\frac 1{c+\sqrt{c^2+1}}$$

Comment: Thank you for all your work! The final equation is neat and beautiful. However, I had some problems modeling it and the results were incorrect. Unfortunately I didn't have time to find where I have made a mistake so I went for the equation visually more complex but easier in modeling. Once again: thank you!